# How to execute a stored procedure in Web API and return a list

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, http-get, webapi

I am learning to develop web api services in .NET Core Web API. Now I trying to execute stored procedure and return a list. But my code does not show the data after stored procedure execution. Any help is much appreciated.

**BL**

```
public string VantageEntities { get; private set; }
public List<SalesAndReturns_RPT> GetOrders(string Year, VantageContext _context)
{
    string conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        sql.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AllSellout", sql))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Year", Year));
            List<SalesAndReturns_RPT> response = null;

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //response = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetDecimal(0));
                }
            }
            sql.Close();
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
    namespace Vantage.Core.Direct.API.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class PieChartController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly VantageContext _context;
            public PieChartController(VantageContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
            [HttpGet]
            public IEnumerable<DAL.Models.SalesAndReturns_RPT> GetOrders(string Year)
            {
                var list = new PieChartMgt().GetOrders(Year, _context);
                return list;
            }
}
}
```

**My stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE AllSellout
@Year VARCHAR(6) 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT BusinessArea, sum(NetValue) as sumNetValue
FROM SalesAndReturns_RPT
WHERE  year(Call_ActualStartDate) = @Year
GROUP BY BusinessArea 
ORDER BY sumNetValue DESC
END
```

**SalesAndReturns_RPT.cs**

```
    public partial class SalesAndReturns_RPT
    {
        public int UID { get; set; }
        public string Distributor { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string DistributorID { get; set; }
        public string Outlet { get; set; }
        public string OutletID { get; set; }
        public string SalesOrgName { get; set; }
        public decimal? NetValue { get; set; }
        public string BusinessArea { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to show SalesAndReturns_RPT class and your stored procedure sql script

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 var response = new  List<SalesAndReturns_RPT>();

   using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var sales= new SalesAndReturns_RPT();
                     sales.BusinessArea = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetString(0));
                    sales.NetValue  = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetDecimal(1));
                
                 response.Add(sales);
                  
                 }
                
            }
     }
     return response;
```

Comment: There is an Error : A new expression requires an argument list or (), [], or {} after type

Comment: @prarthanawickramasinghe It was a typo you need  new SalesAndReturns_RPT();. I  am sorry but it is too early for you to start to create an application code if you don't know how to create an instance. Maybe you have to learn C# a little longer.